# Haskell: Partially applied function, function composition in a raytracer program

Tags: haskell, raytracing, function-composition, partial-application

I have a problem understanding the function composition and the concept of partially applied functions.

Actually I'm writing a small raytracer and have some example implemenentations which I dont understand exactly. Here is one example which I dont understand (https://github.com/ryanl/haskell-raytracer/blob/master/src/RayTracer.hs): It's the function which detects the color of a ray:

```
srdetectcolour' :: Scene -> Ray -> Maybe (Surface, Scalar) -> Colour
srdetectcolour' scene (Ray rx rv) (Just (s,d)) = zipWith (+) lightadded (surface_colour s)
where lightsvisible :: [Light]
      lightsvisible = lightsvisiblefrom intersectpoint scene
      lightadded :: Colour
      lightadded = (foldr (zipWith (+)) black . map effectivelight) lightsvisible
      effectivelight :: Light -> Colour
      effectivelight (v,c) = map (round . (*10000.0) . (/ (vector_sum ((intersectpoint - v) * (intersectpoint - v)))) . fromInteger) c
      intersectpoint = (rx + (mult d rv))
```

I'm interested in the (sub)-function `lightadded` where the `foldr`-part represents a partially applied function (when I'm right). The concept of the function is clear, one wants to add the light of visible lightsource in a point on a surface. For every visible lightsource there is a function `effectivelight` mapped over. What I dont understand is the last parameter of the `foldr`-function ( . map effectivelight) and the complete construction of the function. Can someone explain to me the function (in parts) and the construction of the function? Maybe one can write the function in a more intuitiv way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That last part is not a parameter to foldr, but rather a function composition....

Let's break this apart:

```
lightadded :: Colour
lightadded = (foldr (zipWith (+)) black . map effectivelight) lightsvisible
```

The output of this is a Colour, and

```
foldr (zipWith (+)) black . map effectivelight
```

is therefore a function that takes `lightsvisible` as an input, and outputs a Colour.

Since infix operators bind more closely than anything else, this is actually two functions composed together (ie- `. map effectivelight` is not a parameter to the foldr)

```
foldr (zipWith (+)) black
```

and

```
map effectivelight
```

Notice that `map effectivelight` takes a list as input and gives one as output.  `lightvisible` is an array, `map effectivelight` modifies each element in the list using `effectivelight`, and the result of this is actually the third parameter into the foldr.